# piping the output to another command

Tags: linux, diff

The diff command works only if it has been provided with 2 files. Is it possible to replace one file with the output of another command? The second command mentioned below does not work.

```
$ mysqldump -ushantanu -pPassWord test tbl --skip-extended-insert > to_backup.sql

$ diff  `mysqldump -uroot -pPassWord test some_other_tbl --skip-extended-insert` to_backup.sql 
-bash: /usr/bin/diff: Argument list too long
```

Comment: Can't you just write the output of the other command to a temporary file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you can use process substitution.

```
diff <(mysqldump ...) to_backup.sql
```

Comment: yes as doing `cat `ls`` puts the output of ls in cat's cmdline which causes it to read all the files that ls printed the names of but using `cat <(ls)` has it print what ls printed and that's what you want

Comment: I had tried this. But if there is a space between < and ( then it does not seem to work. What may be the reason?

Comment: The reason is that the construct has no space there.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe one file from stdin

```
 $ mysqldump -uroot -pPassWord test some_other_tbl --skip-extended-insert | diff  to_backup.sql -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-` as a special file name to represent standard input:

```
$ echo foo > bar
$ echo foo > baz
$ cat bar | diff - baz
```

or

```
$ mysqldump -uroot -pPassWord test some_other_tbl --skip-extended-insert | diff - to_backup.sql
```